# More than 5 seeds on 6x6 tefachim!

Tags: kilayim-forbidden-mixture

[Shabbat Mishnah 84b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.84b.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) teaches that one can plant **5** types of seeds on a **6** tefachim by **6** tefachim patch without violating kilayim because one can arrange for plants to be at least **3** tefachim apart.

However, one can actually plant **9** seed types without violating kilayim:

- **4** in the corners,
- **4** in the centercpoints of the sides, and
- **one** in the center of the square

And if you say that a single seed is not significant, then why did the Mishnah bother with the single seed in the center?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Rambam (Commentary on the Mishnah, Kilayim 3:1)](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=37939#p=361&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=), you can indeed do that - and it doesn't have to be a single seed, either; each plant can take up a square of 1x1 tefach:

[image: 9 plants in 1 plot]

But, he says, the mishnah doesn't mention that option, because it's less practical - you end up with only 9 square tefachim planted, whereas if you do five species as below, you get 24 square tefachim planted:

[image: 5 plants in 1 plot]

(Rabbeinu Shimshon on the mishnah there has a whole different understanding of the halachah - he doesn't allow the various species to touch at corners the way the Rambam does - so whether he would allow your configuration, I don't know.)

Comment: From the "practical" POV one should plane **one** kind of seed per patch. ;-)

Comment: @sds there are many reasons to interplant. Here are some: https://www.farmflavor.com/at-home/gardening/interplanting-in-depth-combining-fruits-and-veggies-with-flowers-and-herbs/

Comment: @sds: that depends. You might, for example, end up with too much thyme on your hands.